# ModuleNotFound: No module name 'appium’

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am trying to use record any playback in an iOS app. I am getting this error while running my script.
**"ModuleNotFound: No module name 'appium’**
Can anyone please tell me what is the reason of this?
Same thing i have done for Android in Windows machine but it works and successfully start the session.
Thanks in advance and i am quite new in Appium record and playback.

Answer (score 1):

After re installing Appium i could resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install appium?

Make sure everything is ok by checking `appium-doctor`.

`npm install appium-doctor -g`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have installed appium doctor and it's not showing any error. I am now having another issue as i am using appium version 1.15. It's not launching the app though it is installed after running the script